# Manual delete of indices on elastic search not freeing up space

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have 2TB of indices, trying to manually delete some indices removes them from Kibana, etc. I can delete it via curl or Kibana and it is acknowledged and removed. It is however not freeing up the space.

- I went ahead and also removed the ILM from the index before deleting a few indices, still no luck.
- Although I removed a whole index, also tried POST _forcemerge to no avail.

How can I recover space now that the indices are deleted?

Comment: What do you see when executing the following command before and after deleting your indices: `GET _nodes/stats?filter_path=**.store.size_in_bytes,**.docs.count` ? Do the numbers decrease?

Answer (score 0):

For those who look at this later

Deleting a whole index should free up space instantly! Does not require _forcemerge, etc.

The issue here was the use of a ZFS file system which required a snapshot to be cleared to recover space.